# javascript prompt with name

Tags: javascript, jquery

If my form is filled out completely how do I prompt "Thanks for completing the form, "name"!"

```
function submit_onclick() {
  if(confirm("Thanks for completing the form " + form.name.value))
    document.forms[0].submit();
  else
    return false;
}
```

jquery-1.10.2.min.js script src="jquery.validate.min.js those are my externals via jquery. it validates next to the form. I just need prompt telling the "Name" thanks for completing.

[jsFiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/T9q6e/)

this prompts even when form is empty.

Comment: Can you add your code in jsFiddle?

Comment: As a potential user of your web application, I ask that you not implement this at all.

Comment: You should manually check that all the fields are filled and only in that case ask for confirm. And by manually I mean use JS to check. We are talking about some if.

Comment: BTW I agree with @SeanBright

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T9q6e/... the validation jquery is external... I just need help with a form completion prompt with name when whole form is completed.

Comment: Please don't do this, please don't do this, please don't do this....

Comment: I agree with @SeanBright too. This is a bad design decision.

Comment: jquery-1.10.2.min.js
script src="jquery.validate.min.js those are my externals via jquery. it validates next to the form. I just need  prompt telling the "Name" thanks for completing.

Comment: I understand it is a bad design decision, but those are the directions via School.

Comment: @user2807515 **STOP adding information in 'comments'**. Insert relevant information in you question.

Comment: I am new to Stackoverflow, someone tell me what I need to do, How do I add relevent info to my question?

Comment: Take a look at the jQuery Validate documentation. There should be a way to hook into the `submit` event for the form and only run code when the validation passes muster.

Comment: You can update your question by clicking Edit, then making the appropriate changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to bite the bullet and give you the answer you want, but I **strongly** encourage you to **not ever do this, not in a million years**.

Users *hate* clicking, and even though your dialog box is "personable" (read: addresses them by whatever name they submit), it's *extremely annoying and I don't like it*. But here's how you'd do it, since you asked, using jQuery:

```
function isFormValid() {
    //validate your form here, and return either true or false
}

function submit_onclick() {
    if(isFormValid() && confirm("Thanks for completing the form " + $('#nameField').val()) {
        $('#myForm').submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll remember the info. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on **DesertIvy**'s answer, I think it would be much less annoying for the user if you simply just displayed a message on the web page after the form has completed validation. It would be much less obtrusive. Something like this:

```
<form id="myForm" action="http://example.com/formSubmit.php" method="post">
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validForm() {
    // form validation - return true or false
}

function submit_onclick() {
    if(validForm()) {
        $('#myForm').submit(); // this will submit the form to the form action
    }
}
```

Then on load of the formSubmit.php page, you could display your message in the HTML body.
This is if your server side language is PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['name'])
        echo "Thanks for completing the form " . $_POST['name'] . ".";
    else
        renderFormBody(); // function for rendering the form body
?>
```

Comment: what about displaying that echo string on the same page, under the form? its a dummy form

Comment: It's possible to post to the same form that you fill out in PHP. You just need to check that `$_POST['name']` is set and then display this message if it is set. I'll update my answer to show how it's done.

Comment: My name is DesertIvy and I approve this message. :)